# Serializing to JSON or XML in Pylons

Tags: xml, json, pylons

Is there a quick way to serialize Python data structures to JSON/XML in Pylons, like there is in Django?

Comment: unless you are using python2.5, look no further than the standard library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the jsonify decorator.

http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/1.0/modules/decorators/

```
from pylons.decorators import jsonify

class MyController(BaseController):

    @jsonify
    def action(self):
        my_object = dict(foo='bar')
        return my_object
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes: you are looking for [the simplejson module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/).  Currently, this module is installed when you install Pylons.  Its documentation [lives here](http://simplejson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/simplejson-2.1.2/docs/index.html), and it's a very straightforward module for most use cases.